# rendering a partial fails only on ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

My code is rather similar in concept to the railstutorial by Michael Hartl - the following users part, however it is different enough to ask this question.

The problem before all the details:
When I remove the `remote: true` from _like, everything works smoothly,
When _like.html.erb has `remote: true` I'm getting:

`No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"likes", :artwork_id=>1} missing required keys: [:id]`

And I don't understand why.

The code snippets:

**views/artworks**
**show.html.erb:**

```
<div id="like_link">
    <% if @artwork.liked_users.include?(current_user) then %>
        <%= render 'unlike' %>
    <% else %>
        <%= render 'like' %>
    <% end%>
</div>
```

**_unlike.html.erb:**

```
<%= link_to 'UNLike', like_path(artwork_id: @artwork.id), method: :delete, remote: true %>
```

**_like.html.erb:**

```
<%= link_to 'Like', likes_path(artwork_id: @artwork.id), method: :post, remote: true %>
```

**views/likes**
**create.js.erb:**

```
$("#like_link").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("artworks/unlike")) %>")
$("#likes").html('<%= @artwork.likes_count %>')
```

**destroy.js.erb:**

```
$("#like_link").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("artworks/like")) %>")
$("#likes").html('<%= @artwork.likes_count %>')
```

and the likes controller - **controllers/likes_controller.rb**

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js

  def create
    @artwork = Artwork.find(params[:artwork_id])
    current_user.like!(@artwork)
    respond_with @artwork
  end

  def destroy
    @artwork = Artwork.find(params[:artwork_id])
    current_user.unlike!(@artwork)
    respond_with @artwork
  end
end
```

**routes.rb:**

```
resources :artworks
resources :likes, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problematic line:

```
# _like.html.erb
<%= link_to 'Like', likes_path(artwork_id: @artwork.id), method: :post, remote: true %>
```

The problem here is `likes_path(artwork_id: @artwork.id), method: :post`.  If you check the output of `rake routes` you should see the following two lines for your `likes` resources:

```
likes POST    /likes(.:format)               likes#create
like  DELETE  /likes/:id(.:format)           likes#destroy
```

As you can see the `likes_path` does not take in a parameter except the format, so your `likes_path(artwork_id: @artwork.id)` cannot be mapped to any path.

You should update your route definition with the following:

```
# app/config/routes.rb
resources :artworks do 
  resources :likes, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

With this route definition, your `link_to` calls will be:

```
# _like.html.erb
<%= link_to 'Like', artwork_likes_path(artwork_id: @artwork.id), method: :post, remote: true %>

# _unlike.html.erb
# Replace this_like_id with like_id attribute for this like being destroyed.
<%= link_to 'UNLike', artwork_likes_path(artwork_id: @artwork.id, id: this_like_id), method: :delete, remote: true %>
```

Comment: I didn't encounter this "routes nesting" before... (I'm a noob) - doesn't it interfere with the fact that likes is a standalone model/controller?

Comment: @Boaz, if I understand correctly your `LikesController` is only responsible for creation and deletion of article likes.  If this is not the case and you have other resources that might use `LikesController` then it's better to define custom routes for each like and dislikes, otherwise this solution I believe best solves your question.

Comment: well, I wanted to deduce the like_id inside the controller (it because it's a relationship between current_user and @artwork) - felt more right... In this case a custom route is appropriate.
But your solution is indeed nice. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

here you create routes of

```
resources :likes, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

According RAILS convention it create routes for likes controller there it `use :id` such as `"likes/:id"` not `likes/artwork_id` so please create likes routes manually or follow convention.

Answer (score 0):

you do not have o pass artwork id

```
<%= link_to 'Like', likes_path(@artwork), method: :post, remote: true %>

<%= link_to 'UNLike', like_path(@artwork), method: :delete, remote: true %>
```

and now you can access this in controller by

```
params[:id]
```